# React Native notification badge icon with counting in Android

Tags: android, react-native

I'm new to React Native and I'd like to display notification badge with counting number icon on home screen in **Android**, please see example result image below:

[image]

In **iOS** I'm experimenting on PushNotificationIOS extension but in Android seems to be deadened, I've tried to research for 2 days and still looking for a solution in Android.

Comment: I am not the one downvoting you but you should not include phrases like "Please help" in questions. It does not help to understand your problem, it just bloats the site. Have you read this medium post? https://medium.com/@rossbulat/react-native-working-with-notification-badges-5e60138b83e8

Comment: You can use https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification. This is for Android and iOS. For iOS it uses PushNotificationIOS under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

Ciao, you could use [react-native-firebase](https://rnfirebase.io/). Install it using:

```
npm install --save @react-native-firebase/app
```

Then follow the [Notification guide in React Native Firebase docs](https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/notifications).

Comment: The documentation recommends Notifee, a 3rd party paid notification SDK for custom looks. I reckon it's not possible for Android?

Comment: @CompaqLE2202x I think Notifee is an alternative of react-native-firebase [here](https://notifee.app/react-native/docs/overview) there is a list of free alternatives. Anyway I have never used Notifee but seems that you could use it on Android. [This](https://notifee.app/react-native/docs/android/introduction) is the documentation.

Comment: Yes Notifee is free to use. .